# Hive Metastore is not creating MYSQL or Derby Connection

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, derby

Hive Metastore is not creating MYSQL or Derby Connection.

For Derby

```
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:   hive

schematool -dbType derby -info
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:   hive
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

For mysql

```
schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:   hive
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
*** schemaTool failed ***

schematool -dbType mysql -info
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:   hive
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

What is the issue .

I am running Hive 0.12.0

Comment: DownVoters pls comment

Comment: I have the same problem with 0.14.0. schematool ignores the configurations in hive-site.xml

Comment: had you found solution,may you please help ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with your URL. Modify the URL as follows. Put the mysql port no.

Metastore connection URL:    `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore`

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee

hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794

Here is file-structure 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access Derby, I suspect these should be something like:

```
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

instead of

```
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: where to change these? I am using 0.12.0. I jst extracted the package. Should I create any of the files in extra?Like hive -site

Answer (score 1):

For this specific error "Failed to load driver", you should check if you have the mysql connector copied or has a link in Hive lib folder.

ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar

(Download it if you don't have it within the Java libs)

Similarly get the lib for Derby too.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very broad. To get more information on the root cause, schematool supports the `-verbose` flag:

```
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema -verbose
```

This will print the full stacktrace, which in my case indentified the missing database:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown database 'metastore'