# Hive-2.3.2 metastore with MySQL fails to start

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I have installed apache-hive-2.3.2 with MySQL.
Whenever I am trying to do a `SHOW DATABASES` or any hive command, it is throwing error:

```
hive> show databases;
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

I have configured hive-site.xml like:

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>tomtom</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
```

And in MySQL I have given GRANT permission to 'root':

```
[root@localhost gdm]# mysql -u root -p
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

I have also created the database `metastore` in MySQL:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| metastore          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.53 sec)
```

I also have the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar` in Hive's `lib` directory.
I tried to manually start the hive-metastore:`hive --service metastore`, but its throwing exception:

```
2018-05-05T14:29:38,987 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - Starting hive metastore on port 9083
2018-05-05T14:29:39,882 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2018-05-05T14:29:41,298 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - Retrying creating default database after error: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = root. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2588)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:483)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:297)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:519)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6882)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:7140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:7067)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3307)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1985)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1911)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
        ... 70 more
------
```

I looked for solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451622/hive-metastore-is-not-creating-mysql-or-derby-connection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362406/unable-to-launch-hive-with-mysql-metastore).
but not of much help.
The ConnectionURL I have tried for:
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` as well as,
`jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`. But neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this.
the mysql-connector-java.jar was not compatible. I was using `MySQLv8.0.11` and the connector version was `v5.1`.
I changed the connector with version `v8.0.11`. Still faced timezone CEST issue.
Changed the system timezone (Ref: [Change Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518683/the-server-time-zone-value-cest-is-unrecognized/50201526#50201526))
Restart MySQL: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.